# convert grib to geojson

Tags: geojson, gdal, grib

I want to convert a grib2 file to a geojson with the following format:

```
 {
"type": "FeatureCollection",

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": 0, "sigwaveht": 1.000000 }, "geometry": {     "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 20.5, 77.559374979743737 ], [ 20.756756711040964, 77.5 ], [ 21.0, 77.426829270065582 ], [ 21.5, 77.426829270065582 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": 1, "sigwaveht": 1.000000 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 17.5, 76.879518074163784 ], [ 18.0, 76.840000001907356 ], [ 18.555555592348554, 77.0 ], [ 18.555555592348554, 77.5 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": 2, "sigwaveht": 1.000000 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 28.5, 76.732142838136269 ], [ 29.0, 76.634146323734484 ], [ 29.937500058207661, 77.0 ], [ 29.937500058207661, 77.5 ] ] } },
```

I can accomplish this by using ogr2ogr2 to convert a shape file to a geojson in this format but what can I do to convert a grib2 to a geoJSON of this format?

Answer (score -2):

You can't convert a GRIB, which is a raster format, to GeoJSON, which is a vector format.

What do you expect to achieve? Vector data composed of points where each point is one of the pixels of the raster format?

If this is what you want, you will probably have to code it yourself, I don't think there are any standard tools to do this. Just make a loop over the raster data pixels and write one point feature for every pixel.